# TeamCity. How to trigger some actions on change of certain repo?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm using TeamCity 9.1.7

We have 3 git repos, and they all need to create build.

But, I need to run extra tests if certain of these 3 repos has changes.

I'm using command line in build steps like:

```
if [%env.VAR% == 'foo']
then
    action 1
    action 2
fi
```

Is there any variable which can tell me that only certain of my repos was changed? Or is there any other ways to detect that?

Answer (score 0):

You should set up one more build configuration with spearate triggering rules. Use "copy" build configuration action on project settings page.